# How to export all my SMS messages from my iphone?

Tags: iphone, itunes, sms

I want to export all my sms conversations and messages to my computer any time. I have Windows. CAn it be done via itunes?

Thank you.

Comment: Same answer as before - you need something like iMazing. You can't unpack an iTunes phone backup easily. Ref: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/440386/how-can-i-save-all-my-message-data-onto-my-computer

Comment: Same answer from me to you as well. iMazing is too expensive for something that should be a bundled feature...

Comment: Not sure why you'd think the ability to leave the Apple ecosystem to go elsewhere ought to be built-in.

Comment: https://ting.com/blog/how-to-transfer-text-messages-from-iphone-to-android/

Comment: Im only asking for the ability to have a backup of your data and being able to access it in case something happens to your device. Not too much to ask but thank you for the link anyway.

Comment: Apple provides for you to be able to back up the device and restore it to a new device.

Comment: you still cant access that backup file. Can you?